# How use and deploy Microsoft.Bcl.Async in .Net 4.0?

Tags: .net, async-await, base-class-library

We have following environment:

1) Third-party desktop application App.exe targeted to .Net 4.0.

2) Our plugin.dll targeted to .Net 4.0 and that is dynamically loaded by the App.exe.

3) Our plugin uses Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

4) Along with our plugin we distribute:

- Microsoft.Threadng.Tasks.dll
- Microsoft.Threadng.Tasks.Extensions.dll
- Microsoft.Threadng.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll
- System.Threading.Tasks.dll
- System.IO.dll
- System.Runtime.dll

So, finally we have following directory structure on client system:

```
App /
    App.exe
    App.config
    plugin.dll
    Microsoft.Threadng.Tasks.dll
    Microsoft.Threadng.Tasks.Extensions.dll
    Microsoft.Threadng.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll
    System.Threading.Tasks.dll
    System.IO.dll
    System.Runtime.dll
```

**Our problem** is if client system has .Net 4.5 installed all is working fine, but if client system has .Net 4.0 then the App.exe can't load our plugin:

*System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.*

If we modify App.config to redirect binding to System.Threading.Tasks from our distribution then error goes away. But this not a good solution I think.

I have a strong opinion that we do something wrong, but I don't have enough experience in .Net to resolve this correctly.

Also, is my guess correct that Bcl.Async allows code thet is targeted to .Net 4.0 use async/await without need to be re-targeted to .Net 4.5?

Can any one help me?

**UPDATE Fuslogvw output:**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2/17/2015 @ 5:28:39 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Third-party App\bin\ThirdParty.App.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Administrator
LOG: DisplayName = System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Third-party App/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ThirdParty.App.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Third-party App\bin\ThirdParty.App.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Third-party App/bin/System.Threading.Tasks.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Third-party App\bin\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.6.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Does your project target .Net 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: Very hard to guess what it could have found, you need to post the trace you get out of Fuslogvw.exe to nail it down.

Comment: @HansPassant, log attached

Comment: Can you show the assembly redirects on your config file?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, ThirdParty.App.exe.config don't have any redirects.

Comment: I've used that recently on a 4.0 project and there are a few nodes under /configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding in the configuration file. And they are needed for the correct assembly binding to happen.